# angular partials - is the best practises to put this in public/ or views/ or somewhere else?

Tags: angularjs, express

I am building a pinterest-type clone for learning the node and I am wondering whether it is best to put my partial views (for rendering all the pins for example) in the public/partials folder, or put this into the views/
folder.

Thank you

Comment: the framework does not enforce any requirement on this;  whatever your standard is for your team environment is should work.  This is mostly a matter of opinion, and nobody can tell you what standards your team should adopt.

Comment: hello friend.  i do not have a team only myself for learning.  thanks i will put it in the public then

Answer (score 1):

It's up to you but i'd suggest John Papa's styleguide. The guide recommends keeping all common elements of a component in the same directory. You can organize that directory however you like but over organizing can be as bad as under organizing.

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y140

So for example. If I am writing an app I may have a header component. My app structure would look like this-

```
app/
    header/
        header.tpl.html
        header.controller.js
        header.service.js
```

If I find my component is getting large and there are a lot of templates (or directives, or controllers, or services) I might organize that further (**but not until that point**)

```
app/
    header/
        partials/
            header.menu.partial.html
            header.search.partial.html
            header.login.partial.html
            header.logo.partial.html
        header.tpl.html
        header.controller.js
        header.service.js
```

But generally I organize by type.

```
app/
    header/
        search/
            header.search.directive.js
            header.search.partial.html
            header.search.controller.js
            header.search.service.html
        menu/
            header.menu.directive.js
            header.menu.partial.html
            header.menu.controller.js
            header.menu.service.html
        header.tpl.html
        header.controller.js
        header.service.js
```

So you should decide what you think makes sense but if you're trying to find a battle tested pattern I'd recommend looking at John Papa for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

While the Angular framework is un-opinionated  on how you store your components, different people/teams adapt what works for them. Usually just being uniform is more than enough. However there are certain best practices put together by the community and other experienced folks.

A good place to start is:  http://yeoman.io/

In a nutshell, yeoman is a generator that has many templates published by the opensource community. They usually make a great seed template.

A good place to start looking for templates is [generator](http://yeoman.io/generators/) page. If you want a quick fix for a Angular project, [Angular Template](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular#readme) by Yeoman team is my favorite.